# How to find Employee multiple work location history based on effective from date and to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say an employee stayed in multiple location with effective from date and to date.
I need get the years(0 yrs 0 mnths) he spent in each location with columns as,
emp id,
location,
period stayed in each location

He may work in same location with diff effective from date and hence the group by doesn't work. Hence it should order by effective from date of employee.
Expected result:

```
empid location Period he spent
1      chn      2 years
2      mum      3 yrs 2 mnths
3      chn      5 mnths
4      mum      3 mnths
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stackoverflow! Kindly provide more details on your question like a sample data along with the expected results. More details will make it easier for other people to help you out :) For more information, see the help section. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: so what kind of data you have now in your table? could you show us that too?

Comment: My current output is
CHN              GS0052 NULL 1977-02-02 00:00:00.000 1999-01-01 00:00:00.000 1999-05-31 23:59:59.000
BANG             GS0052 NULL 1977-02-02 00:00:00.000 1999-06-01 00:00:00.000 1999-06-05 23:59:59.000
CHN              GS0052 NULL 1977-02-02 00:00:00.000 1999-06-06 00:00:00.000 1999-12-31 23:59:59.000
CHN              GS0052 NULL 1977-02-02 00:00:00.000 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 2001-01-18 23:59:59.000
CHN              GS0052 NULL 1977-02-02 00:00:00.000 2001-01-19 00:00:00.000 NULL

Comment: select h10.C29_Location_code as 'Location',
 h01.H01_Emp_Num, 
 h01.H01_known_as,
 h01.H01_birth_date,
 h10.H10_Effective_Date_From,
 h10.H10_Effective_Date_To
 from  H01_identfcatn h01(nolock),H10_EmpAsgn h10(nolock) 
where h10.H01_emp_num = h01.H01_emp_num
and  h10.C03_Organisation_code = h01.C03_Organisation_code
and   h01.H01_emp_num like  'GS0052'
and  h10.C03_Organisation_code = 'RAMCO'
order by H10_Effective_Date_From

Comment: Please use the edit button in the question, don't post code or data into comments